# Heads up: editing of long lines of code in Chrome no longer possible

Tags: discussion, google-chrome

Google Chrome pushed an update earlier this month, 60.0.3112.101, which makes it impossible to format code containing long lines. Maybe it even started in an earlier version, I just now noticed it:

```html
<textarea cols="20" rows="10">01234567890123456789</textarea>
```

When running the snippet, try to put four spaces at the start of the "0123..." line. After two spaces, the browser will automatically **insert a line break**. This of course breaks the intended formatting.

Not really sure this is on-topic for Meta, but wanted to post it to warn others.

I noticed it while editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860235/how-to-add-service-adddbcontext-in-class-library-net-core) on Windows 10. I wanted to turn:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:LocalConnectionString"]));
```

Into:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:LocalConnectionString"]));
```

For readability, but can now no longer do that from the browser. Try [editing this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/355580/edit) and prepending spaces to the line starting with `options` above.

Note: copy-pasting four spaces does bypass this ridiculous behavior, so it's not even implemented consistently. I can't find the change yet in Chrome's release notes.

Comment: Hmm.  I have 60.0.3112.101 and I'm not getting a line break.  I do have user scripts so maybe those a helping?

Comment: I've seen this for a few days now, it's intensely annoying.

Comment: I've seen this before but instead of putting four spaces I've had to select the code button. Didn't think it was browser specific so never really took much notice.

Comment: @Nathan it's on Windows, don't know if that matters.

Comment: *Yet another reason why IE will always be the superior internet browser.* /s (joking aside. I get line breaks as mentioned. Chrome 60.0.3112.101 Win 7)

Comment: Not sure.  I've got Win7 pro 64 bit.  Although this update did break a website I use.  I cant log into anymore.  Hopefully they update soon.

Comment: @Ihazkode Firefox master race!

Comment: Chrome always regresses somewhere with every major release, it's comical (I tried keeping track of each thing that broke from version 39 to around 43 before I quickly got tired of it). The majority of these do get fixed by the next release, but not even Internet Explorer suffered from regressions every single release.

Comment: @BoltClock there's also a funny new bug (or perhaps a regression): for every character you type in the post editor on (meta) Stack Overflow, the favicon blinks...

Comment: @CodeCaster: Which just reminds me of this: https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/big_24.html

Comment: Reproduced it in Chrome for MacOS version 59.0.3071.115.

Comment: MacOS 61.0.3163.59 (beta) - There's a linebreak after a single space for me.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome broke `white-space: pre-wrap` (i.e. it no longer follows [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#valdef-white-space-pre-wrap)). The alternative would be to use `white-space: pre` but that will affect text as well, which may be less than ideal.

```html
<textarea cols="20" rows="10" style="white-space: pre">01234567890123456789</textarea>
```

Comment: Yeah but ... no.

Comment: The line break that's inserted is an actual newline character. I've never heard of Internet Explorer ever breaking CSS so hard that it mutates the DOM. I've said for many years that Chrome and Safari are the new IE, but I think Chrome has truly outdone IE on this one.

Comment: _The alternative would be to use_ Safari, Firefox, Opera, Edge, ...

Comment: (Before anyone mentions [crashing IE6 with CSS](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Hamachiya2/20070804/browser_crasher), several years ago one of my media queries started crashing Chrome while I wasn't looking, and [it would seem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/tr17_zfCdvc/yeQVmCC99TAJ) [I wasn't the](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=149855) [only one affected](http://iamkeir.com/post/26647025450/firefox-media-query-breakpoints-wtf#comment-676481137).)

Comment: Interestingly, querying the DOM does not show any newline characters being inserted nor does it appear as a newline character when using the element inspector @BoltClock. This seems to be purely a rendering bug.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: I tried it again, experimenting with different numbers of keystrokes, and I found that the text simply soft-wraps after the first two spaces are inserted, without a newline; however, a newline *is* created after the third keystroke, and only then. I was able to confirm this by copying the snippet from the question and adding a keyup listener to log the content length (which is shown to increase by 2 after the third keystroke), as well as copying the content out of the textarea into a text editor.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, I was looking at the `textContent` not the `value`. Apparently both `textContent` and `innerHTML` trim the whitespace. It does in fact insert a newline into the value.

Comment: So... considering they're throwing the spec out the window for no apparent benefit, shouldn't we just file a bug report?