# Can't Seem to get This Code Into a Codeblock

Tags: bug, code-formatting, code, formatting, google-chrome

I wrote an answer that uses a ton of conversions:

```
chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::time_point(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::duration<double>(input))))
```

I can seem to get this into a code block here, but for some reason I cannot in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495821/2642059

Is this bug somehow specific to Chrome:

> Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Or is there something about the state in that answer which is preventing it?

Comment: Huh... Selecting it and hitting Ctrl+K will do it, but trying to add spaces puts a linebreak after two. Only in Chrome.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, good call. I'll do that after I've given this question a chance to get answered.

Comment: Putting four spaces at the beginning of that line works just fine in Firefox.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. (remark: you should really split the code into multiple lines, thanks to the verbosity of C++ :/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heads up: editing of long lines of code in Chrome no longer possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355580/1016716)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Testing with a textarea produces this result when four spaces is typed in (encoded so we can see whitespace characters):

[image]

Seems like Chrome inserts a linefeed character `%0A` after two spaces, as the current unbroken line is too long. `%20` is a normal space.

This behavior was reported on the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gqFlu8gAoqw)

To workaround this, select the code block and click on the [Code Sample] button, or break up the line of code with spaces like [how I edited your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50495821/revisions).

Comment: i think the [chromium bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) would be a more appropriate place to report it