# Using spaces when editing when line word wraps acts as an 'enter' in Chrome

Tags: bug, edits, google-chrome

I came across a really strange bug when editing an answer in Chrome just now.  I was updating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079906/vba-filtering-more-than-2-criteria/55282574#55282574) and my spacebar was working like the enter key (almost).  It would add a space and a return.

The error does not occur when editing other answers, and is not reproducible in Firefox.  Here is a screen capture of what is happening.

1. I click edit.
2. I begin pressing space before the code block (which is a single very long string of characters).
3. I backspace (notice that there are spaces as well as enters added).

[image: GIF of editor behavior]

At first I thought it might be some extension, but I can reproduce this in incognito as well.

Comment: What's that [dog](https://imgur.com/zP8Qgj0)?

Comment: It's a user script, my friend called Natty.

Comment: No need to remove anything, it happens already the moment you try to add a space before that line.

Comment: Looks like wonky behavior in Chrome when the line is forced to wrap, IMO. Probably not anything to do with Stack Overflow. Try pasting a space instead of typing it. It sort of works. But you only see a change in the preview, there is no change in the text area itself.

Comment: I suspected that there were some weird Unicode control characters, but there weren’t any.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this bug is due to the word wrap of a very long line with no word breaks.  Adding whitespace in the middle of that long line makes this no longer happen.  Still a weird bug though.

Comment: Reproduced under Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 without any extensions running (incognito tab)

Comment: I repro this regularly. The workaround is to remove all spaces, then select the block and click the formatting button  in the toolbar. Or, you can now use the triple-backtick fences.

Comment: This seems to be a dublicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355580/heads-up-editing-of-long-lines-of-code-in-chrome-no-longer-possible It seems like they bought back this bug

Comment: @Ferrybig Yup, looks like a dup.  So it's a Chrome bug.  I'll send in a report over there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are seeing is because it is a very long string with no spaces in it. If you where to break it up somewhat and place spaces between the '+' signs you will notice that behavior will change.

Personally I would suggest adding some spaces into that line of code to make it a bit easier to read.

I was able to reproduce the behavior in Vivaldi (which is based on chrome) and prevent it from happening by adding in some extra spaces. Though as a note it still happened somewhat when spaces where just added around the '+' sign.

Answer (score -2):

I too suffer a lot with this.

Click <kbd>Space</kbd> once. When it goes to the next line; move the cursor to the above line and then use the <kbd>space</kbd> key to add bare spaces.

Works perfect for me.
Also instead of formatting code using 4space you can also use three ` symbols before and after the code to format it.

```
`` `// I had to use space else it creates problem. Click edit button for better understanding.
//Code here 
`` `
```